# Constant unseen by compiler

Tags: c, makefile, configure, automake

I have a problem with code below. It throws me errors which tells me nothing.

I have a file memory.h where i have:

```
#ifndef BLOCK_SIZE
#define BLOCK_SIZE 8
#endif
```

I have also configuration.ac file with fragment as below:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([block-size],
    [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-block-size],["Define blocksize to initialize with. Default value: 8]")],
        [bsize="$withval"],
        [])

if test ! -z "${bsize}"; then
        if test  "${bsize}" > 0 ; then
                AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([BLOCK_SIZE], [$b_size], [Defining block size in bytes])
        else
                AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([BLOCK_SIZE], [8], [Default block size : 8B])
        fi
fi
```

Later i used command `./configure --with-block-size=16 --with-allocator=STR_MIN` to finalize making makefile. But now ehen i use `make` command i get a buch of errors:

```
memory.c: In function 'initialize':
memory.c:15:59: error: expected expression before ')' token
memory.c: In function 'allocate':
memory.c:26:41: error: expected expression before ')' token
memory.c:53:56: error: expected expression before ';' token
memory.c: In function 'defragment':
memory.c:140:73: error: expected expression before ')' token
memory.c: In function 'diagnoze':
memory.c:174:183: error: expected expression before ',' token
```

All lines with error looks like this:

```
mem -> unused_list -> address = malloc(count * BLOCK_SIZE);
new -> address = space -> address + size * BLOCK_SIZE;
```

It looks like compiler do not see BLOCK_SIZE at all. Now there is just a question why. 
Knowing me I have probably eat latter or two in this code. But i can't find it and have no clue what more can cause this problem. All other commands of automake which i used earlier (including ./con..) didn't throw any errors.

Comment: @Dcortez.. Does you header file have a guard i.e. to avoid redefinition?

Comment: it has `#ifndef _MEMORY_H #define _MEMORY_H some code #endif`

Comment: @Dcortez.. Just to confirm `memory.c` includes `memory.h` and it's path is available as part of the `make` file construct through `-I` option. Can you confirm if this is the case?

Comment: memory.c includes memory.h I'm not sure about the second, but it uses a command like this `gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src/include include -g -O2 -MT memory.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/memory.Tpo -c memory.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/memory.o`. memory.h is in './src/include' so it should be so

Comment: I have no idea why answers has dissapeard. Any way using quotes `AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([BLOCK_SIZE], ["$b_size"], [Defining block size in bytes])` here changed error to `memory.c:15:47: error: invalid operands to binary * (have 'int' and 'char *')` So now compiler sees it but treat like a char* instead of int as I wanted. LDFLAGS in makefile are empty.

Comment: What is in the config.h that autoconf generates?  In particular, the line that sets `BLOCK_SIZE`

Comment: `/* Default block size : 8B */
#define BLOCK_SIZE ""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stupid mistake as I thought. I just had to change line:

```
AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([BLOCK_SIZE], [$bsize], [Defining block size in bytes])
```

There was no missing quotes as someone suggested, but just simple _ to much. 
Thanks for help anyways.

Comment: For anyone like me trying to figure out where this magical _ is: The variable was originally set as `$b_size`